# Passing value from one RxJS operator to another

Tags: rxjs, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Here is my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class TraitementDetailEffects {
    ingoing_loadDetail: { traitementID: number, obs: Promise<any> };
    @Effect()
    loadTraitementDetail$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ETraitementDetailActions.loadTraitementDetail),
        map((action: LoadTraitementDetail) => action.payload),
        switchMap((traitementID) => {
            if (this.ingoing_loadDetail && this.ingoing_loadDetail.traitementID === traitementID) {
                return this.ingoing_loadDetail.obs;
            }
            const obs = this.traitementsService.loadDetail(traitementID);
            this.ingoing_loadDetail = {traitementID: traitementID, obs: obs};
            return obs;
        }),
        map(result => {
            this.ingoing_loadDetail = null;
            //here I don't have access to traitementID :'(
            return new LoadTraitementDetailSuccess(traitementID, result);
        })
    );

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private traitementsService: TraitementsService
    ) {

    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass the variable or value traitementID to the last map.

I tried to avoid the last map with an async await but then I get a weird errors "Effect dispatched an invalid action" and "Actions must have a type property" (FYI all my actions have a type property).

Comment: `traitementID` is in a different scope, in a separate arrow function, you *don't* try to pass it along. The observable you return from the `switchMap` will need to include the result of `loadDetail` *and* the `traitementId`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't really want to alter my loadDetail coz it returns a promise with a specific type of Object. Do you see another way around maybe making a higher closure ?

Comment: You don't need to alter loadDetail, you can e.g. `return obs.pipe(map(result => ({ result, traitementID })))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried but I still don't know how to retrieve the traitementID  in the last map, I tried map(result,traitementID) but that was dumb... reuslt doesn't seem to have a traitementID property. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Then give a [mcve] of that - `map(result,traitementID)` is clearly not what I showed above.

Comment: ok thank you " is clearly not what I showed above" enlightened me, can you write your answer I would like to give you some point.

Answer (score 2):

Try to bake this id into observable's resolve, like:

```
            switchMap((traitementID) => {
                return this.traitementsService.loadDetail(traitementID).pipe(
                           map(detail => ({detail,traitementID}))
                       );

            }),
            map(({detail,traitementID}) => {
                ...
            })
```